# Java Sigar huge RAM usage

Tags: java, ram

i'm using a Sigar library on linux workstation server (dist. Mint). this is my code:

```
    ConnectionUtils connection = new ConnectionUtils();
    Sigar sigar = new Sigar();
    String query = "";
    connection.openConnection();

    Mem mem;
    CpuPerc cpuperc;
    FileSystemUsage filesystemusage;


    long RAM;
    long CPU;
    long HDD;

    while(true) {

        mem = sigar.getMem();
        cpuperc = sigar.getCpuPerc();
        filesystemusage = sigar.getFileSystemUsage("/");

        RAM  = Math.round(mem.getUsedPercent());
        CPU  = Math.round((cpuperc.getCombined()*100));
        HDD = Integer.valueOf((int) (filesystemusage.getUsePercent()*100));

        query = "UPDATE ServerInfo SET RAM="+RAM+",CPU="+CPU+",HDD="+HDD+" WHERE ServerName=\"XgenVPS\"";
        connection.sendQuery(query);
        System.out.println("informacje sostały pomyśnie wysłane do bazy danych"); 
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

}

and its after few hours increased RAM usage, and after a day crashed - program stopped interval and no responging, but won't dropped with fatal error. can anyone help me? i want to this program will be working for many days without that bugs.

oh. This is from ConnectionUtils functions:

```
private Connection conn;

private String host = "localhost";
private String port = "3306";
private String database = "xgen-dashboard";
private String user = "root";
private String pass = "asdzxcasdzxc123";

public ConnectionUtils() {

}

public synchronized void openConnection(){
    if(!isConnected()){
        try{
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+host+":"+port+"/"+database+"?user="+user+"&password="+pass+"&useSSL=false");
        } catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public synchronized void closeConnection(){
    if(isConnected()){
        try{
            conn.close();
        } catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public boolean isConnected() {
    try{
        if(conn == null) return false;
        if(conn.isClosed()) return false;
    } catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;
}

public ResultSet sendQuery(String query) {
    try {
        return conn.createStatement().executeQuery(query);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        try {
             conn.createStatement().executeUpdate(query);
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;

}
```

Comment: As a first step you might have a look with `jmap -histo pid` (pid the pid fo your app). You never close your created statements. Have a look on that.

Comment: oh. so how to right close the statements? is the statements was still on RAM until program close?

Comment: You might have a look on the JDBC tutorial https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html. Where your memory hog is you can find out for example with `jmap` as already said. We can only make assumptions on that. First find the reason for the memory consumption. Then find a solution for the issue. If necessary raise a new question for it.

Comment: ok, i finnaly have time to anwser. i opened a jmap -histo. this is what i got after few seconds:
http://www.wepaste.com/jmap/